# Display Image In Gallery/Photos

Tags: android, android-intent, android-permissions, mediastore, android-external-storage

I have an in-app image that eventually will be pulled from a database, to simplify the app (for now) I just want to view the image in an external app such as Gallery or Photos.

**Original Attempt**

```
 //opens image with external program
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

 Uri imgUri = Uri.parse("content://" + item.getImage());
 intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");

 holder.itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
 break;
```

This click event is taking part in an adapter, so you might have to ignore "holder.itemView.getContext()". I am finding that majority of posts on Stacked were about pulling in a photo from storage to view in an ImageView. Additionally I also found that the majority of answers are pre-2017 and are different from modern results.

My min SDK is 23.

I have included:

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider"/>
```

I am testing on the Android Emulator (7.0 - API 24)

After some more research I have upgraded my code to a 2019 version, shown below. Side Note: Permission Requests for WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE are successful

**Latest Upgrade**

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, item.getImage());
Uri contentUri = holder.itemView.getContext().getContentResolver().
          insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(contentUri, "image/*");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, contentUri);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

holder.itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
```

Not sure why this has been so difficult, I am getting a little overwhelmed and I am sure the correction is easy enough.

Comment: For viewing images, have a look at the Glide library

Comment: Is it better practice to view images in the app, rather than with a 3rd party app? I figured this route would be easier than having to set up various functions (print, email, copy, etc).

Comment: You would be viewing images in your app. You are using a library which delivers functionality to your app. It is common practice to do this.

Comment: I ended up going with Glide, I have used it before but the content online for pushing files to 3rd party is limited. Though might get tough when I get to handling PDF and custom files